# What directory do I install a virtualenvironment?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, kivy, virtualenv

I want to install Kivy and use it in IntelliJ. Here is step 1 in installing Kivy:

> 1.First create the environment named kivy_venv in your current directory:
>
> > python -m virtualenv kivy_venv

When opening command prompt I am in the directory "C:\Users\jfran>" Should I paste the command into here? Or should I create a project in IntelliJ and use the command prompt in that directory?

EDIT: Here is the link to the Kivy installation steps https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: If I wasn't sure, I wouldn't execute that in my home directory but one that isn't already used for anything else. In any case, start with reading the documentation in order to understand what this command does!

Comment: So if I add it to another directory that I created, would Python know its there when I code? Or would I have to import it into my project after its created?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+where+to+create